# Проиндексировать документы .fb2 в Apache Solr с вычиткой метаданных в отдельные поля

Tags: search, index, solr, fb2

Есть коллекция книг в формате ***.fb2***

Как проиндексировать документы в Solr с вычиткой метаданных в отдельные поля коллекции?

Необходимо проиндексировать эти файлы с вычиткой полей "название книги" и "дата создания" из файлов ***.fb2***

Пробовал делать индексацию описанную в документации... но там есть примеры для xml и некоторых других форматов, которые по умолчанию поддерживает Apache Solr...

fb2 файлы - это тоже по своей структуре xml документы.

Но вот как их проиндексировать и получить из них поля  - непонятно.

Ссылки, подсказки, видео - любой информации на эту тему буду рад!